# Can GCC be modified to be used as static lib?

Tags: c++, gcc, static

I'm developing app that works in env where process forking is prohibited. Can i use GCC in my project as static lib? I'd like to have command-line-like API like `int execute(int argc, char *argv);` in order to pass the same string just like using regular GCC executable. Is it possible?

As gcc uses binutils (also executables) it would be great to have callbacks in order to intercept invocations or built-in binutils (am i dreaming?).

PS. It's not for viruses or smth dangerous, it's for embedded system.

Comment: nope, at least not easily enough to be practical/feasible. GCC was specifically designed to explicitly prohibit this kind of usage because Richard Stallman is a paranoid and wanted to avoid any non-free use of GCC. Maybe look into clang, which is already a library.

Comment: `Clang` would be great but unfortunately it does not have `AVR` back-end at the moment. What are limitations of using gcc as embedded compiler?

Comment: In theory - yes, but in practice far less so. When you invoking gcc - it calls a lot of other things, like `cpp`, `ar`, `ld`, etc., so even if you can embed gcc itself, it wouldn't give you much.

Comment: @keltar. well it can be solved in next way: every executable used by GCC can be modified to provide API just like i'm asking for GCC (`int execute(int argc, char* argv)`) and every call to them can be intercepted and invoked via that API. interception can be done just replacing fork call in source code to my callback. in theory

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant - I doubt that is the reason. There is nothing preventing people from bundling standalone GCC with non-free software. I think the issue of GCC is one of ancient, outdated, non-future-proof design.

Comment: Why not just `vfork` and `exec` gcc itself? Or OS is that weak? Can gcc even work on that host? (not target this hw - that's different)

Comment: @keltar. can you explain more detailed about vfork/exec? It's not weakness problem, it's security policy. Gcc can work in host OS (and i would just execute it as usual if not security policy) but i need it's target to be `AVR` (not host, host is `ARM`). So compiled by GCC executables will just be sent to connected device and work there.

Comment: @4ntoine not sure I get what your environment is. I meant, your `execute` call could call `vfork` system call (which make a clone of process), then replace new process with gcc (e.g. with `execve` call) and pass required arguments. Then your process just wait for results from child process. Then do with result anything you want. It isn't embedding of course.

Comment: no, i need to use gcc as static library and not as executable. i can't execute `gcc -c file.c -o file` and i'd like to invoke `int result = execute(1, "gcc -c file.c -o file");` from my app. forking is prohibited for security reason

Comment: @4ntoine - you'd like but what you gonna do about it? GCC was never intended to be used this way, and I doubt it will be an easy thing getting it to. Your best chances are starting a new process, running whatever version of GCC you want against whatever code and whatever parameters you want and then get the result.

Comment: @ddriver. i can't create new process. that's the reason. "GCC was never intended to be used this way,". ok. but what prevents me from using it that way? are there any real limitations that can't be workaround

Comment: Why is that? Anyway, of course you can do everything you've written so far, but it will take very long time.

Comment: @keltar. i've already replied few times: "i can't create new process for security reason".

Comment: @ddriver you can doubt it, but Stallman in person asserted that. google for it if you don't believe me (for whatever reason).

Comment: @4ntoine it isn't getting anywhere. Gcc itself creates processes, so it is allowed to it, but not to you? Weeeeell maybe, you know better. Not sure if it adds to security though.

Comment: gcc uses system calls to create process (to run external tools like `ar`, `ld`) so it will just get exception when trying to do it in my env. the point is that i can forward invocation and do it myself (run them as static libs too)

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant - I don't doubt he doesn't want GCC integrated in non-free software, I just doubt that is the reason for making GCC so stiff and poorly designed mess :) Maybe he used that as an excuse to justify that mess, but it was a lucky coincidence at best..

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant and besides, GCC has been integrated in a library for a non-free software, at least that's how t seems, there are 1 or 2 apps on google play which seem to do that. Is he doing anything about it?

Comment: even stock Android allows to run executables BTW. So i would just use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("");` instead. Unfortunately you can't understand my env restriction so i would prefer this conversation to be more constructive.

Comment: Well, where I was leading this conversation to - is that fact that gcc can't run on that host (because it can't run processes). So, you need to port gcc to it - that is a part of your problem too. All that surely doable, but will take months.